# How do I set the socket timeout in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, network-programming

How do you set the timeout for blocking operations on a Ruby socket?

Comment: Found a much better solution than your accepted one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12111120/216314

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Comment: [Timeout module with exclusive locks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15304835/1301972).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution I found which appears to work is to use [Timeout::timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/index.html):

```
require 'timeout'
    ...
begin 
    timeout(5) do
        message, client_address = some_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    end
rescue Timeout::Error
    puts "Timed out!"
end
```

Comment: Using timeout is a mistake.  Due to green theards, anything that blocks on IO will block the timeout thread as well thus stopping it from working.

Comment: @Sardathrion, thanks for the feedback but a solution would be better than a negative comment :)

Comment: Ruby threads are broken I am afraid.  Find a better language -- harsh but true.

Comment: The SystemTimer gem can be used to implement safe timeouts on Ruby 1.8. Ruby 1.9 does not have the timeout limitation described by Sardathrion since it uses native threads.

Comment: This uses threads for timeouts which is very bad for performance in multithreaded applications in ruby. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12111120/216314

Comment: @TylerBrock I am using Rails 3 with Apache/Passenger, which from my understanding is not multithreaded. I think Passenger spawns a new process for each request. Is your solution still recommended over this?

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the `Timeout::timeout` implementation above is reasonable for ruby 1.9.x and newer?

Comment: It is only reasonable if performance is not an issue but yes, this is perfectly reasonable Ruby code. The nuance is in the details of the implementation of the language.

Comment: Ruby 2.x is not using green threads anymore, so all the comments of this not working should be invalid now.

Answer (score 15):

The timeout object is a good solution.

This is an example of asynchronous I/O (non-blocking in nature and occurs asynchronously to
the flow of the application.)

```
IO.select(read_array
[, write_array
[, error_array
[, timeout]]] ) => array or nil
```

Can be used to get the same effect.

```
require 'socket'

strmSock1 = TCPSocket::new( "www.dn.se", 80 )
strmSock2 = TCPSocket::new( "www.svd.se", 80 )
# Block until one or more events are received
#result = select( [strmSock1, strmSock2, STDIN], nil, nil )
timeout=5

timeout=100
result = select( [strmSock1, strmSock2], nil, nil,timeout )
puts result.inspect
if result

  for inp in result[0]
    if inp == strmSock1 then
      # data avail on strmSock1
      puts "data avail on strmSock1"
    elsif inp == strmSock2 then
      # data avail on strmSock2
      puts "data avail on strmSock2"
    elsif inp == STDIN
      # data avail on STDIN
      puts "data avail on STDIN"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the non blocking approach is the way to go.
I tried the mentioned above article and could still get it to hang.
this article [non blocking networking](http://peasleer.wordpress.com/2006/11/14/non-blocking-networking-in-ruby/) and the jonke's approach above got me on the right path.   My server was blocking on the initial connect so I needed it to be a little lower level.
the socket rdoc can give more details into the connect_nonblock

```
def self.open(host, port, timeout=10)
 addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(host, nil)
 sock = Socket.new(Socket.const_get(addr[0][0]), Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)

 begin
  sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, addr[0][3]))
 rescue Errno::EINPROGRESS
  resp = IO.select([sock],nil, nil, timeout.to_i)
  if resp.nil?
    raise Errno::ECONNREFUSED
  end
  begin
    sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, addr[0][3]))
  rescue Errno::EISCONN
  end
 end
 sock
end
```

to get a good test.   startup a simple socket server and then do a ctrl-z to background it

the IO.select is expecting data to come in on the input stream within 10 seconds.   this may not work if that is not the case.

It should be a good replacement for the TCPSocket's open method.

Comment: This works for me very well indeed.  Timeout should not be used under any circumstances because of MRI's green threads.

Comment: A non-blocking connect comes up writable when ready. Use `IO.select(nil,[sock],nil, timeout.to_i)`