# Is there any default timeout for the gets function of the TCPSocket class

Tags: ruby

Is there any default timeout for the `gets` function of the `TCPSocket` class? How can I check it out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [`IO.select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-select) method allows you to set timeouts. See "[Set socket timeout in Ruby via SO_RCVTIMEO socket option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853516/set-socket-timeout-in-ruby-via-so-rcvtimeo-socket-option/12111120#12111120)."

Comment: @the Tin Man I don't need to set it, I just need to check it out