# Ruby programming: skip If statement if taking too long to complete

Tags: ruby

How would I program a script to proceed to a function, if an if statement takes far too long to complete?

I am currently in a situation, where a chunk of code (depending on the network) can take anywhere from half a second, to half an hour to complete, and I am researching a code patch which would cause the code to skip the if statement and proceed to a new code function if it takes over 10 seconds to complete.

I suspect that the answer may lie within threads, however I am unsure as its a programming concept with which I have no experience. I am open to any answers, no matter how elaborate.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic solution is to use [Timeout::timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/231662/393701 for an answer fitting your question.